# Confused over an edit rejection

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742495/jquery-conflict) and decided that it could do with some improvement. I [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1884717) which was subsequently rejected by three users all with the same reason:

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning
>   or intent of the post would be lost.

I don't see how the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost with the changes I made though. Can someone help explain this to me for future reference when editing?

Comment: Why did you remove the links? They were useful and probably the reason for the rejection.

Comment: I didn't remove them. See the markdown difference.

Comment: Fair enough. But at first glance, they are gone. Many reviewers don't really put enough time into properly reviewing.

Comment: Yes, they are hard to see with rendered difference now that you mention it. Perhaps the CSS could do with updating to make links stand out more in this mode? I'll make a request for this.

Comment: You should say "embedding links" first thing, personally I always check and look for the links but as you see many won't do that and just assume you removed the links.

Comment: I would try reediting and put a comment in why you changed and hope you get better reviewers as making links is a good thing - however I doubt reviewers who did not check hat would read the reason :( This would make a good audit question

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd will do so in the future, thanks.

Comment: @Mark It would be a good audit I think :) I've made a suggestion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175811/can-the-css-be-adjusted-to-make-links-stand-out-more-in-rendered-output-mode) though that may make it a less effective audit if implemented though.

Comment: Looks like a solid edit to me. I would have aproved it (and I reject a lot).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175813/make-it-obvious-that-a-link-was-added-in-the-diff

Comment: I have resubmitted the edit and it has since been approved. I made it clear with my description that I embedded the links as @ShaWizDowArd advised.

Comment: Nice, 100% success this time. :) (i.e. not a single rejection)