# Can the CSS be adjusted to make links stand out more in rendered output mode

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I recently got an edit rejected and upon [asking for clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175810/confused-over-an-edit-rejection), it emerged that based on my [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1884717), it looked like I had removed the links from the post when I hadn't.

It is clear that the links are still there if someone views the edit suggestion in markdown mode, but unfortunately not all reviewers take time to do this before hitting the reject button.  For this reason, I suggest making links more visible in rendered output mode for suggested edits.

Comment: Similar but not the same I think. I am talking about highlighting the link using CSS to make it obvious that it is there whereas the linked question is talking about adding a new section that shows when links are changed.

Comment: No, the suggestion is that "hyperlinks needs to jump out and punch you." They've provided a *solution* that they think covers the problem. If you think your solution is better suited, you're more than welcome to post it as an answer there. But we don't need separate questions for each and every solution a user comes up with to the same problem. That just makes them all harder to find.

Comment: I reread the question again on your comment. It still seems like two different issues to me. My issue is related to it appearing that links have been removed in suggested edits when in fact they have been embedded. The linked question deals with users surreptitiously changing link locations in the background while making it appear that they lead to the same location as before the edit.

Comment: It deals with all forms of links being changed (added and removed as well). It would cover your situation perfectly,as in your specific case it would show up as a title change rather than a URL change (the actual link to "website").